# Unable to create a constant value - only primitive types

Tags: c#, linq

Two simple queries - the exception occurs in :

```
matchings.Any(u => product.ProductId == u.ProductId)
```

What is wrong? If I write `true` instead it all is good.

```
var matchings = (from match in db.matchings 
                 where match.StoreId == StoreId 
                 select match).ToList();

var names = (from product in db.Products
             where matchings.Any(u => product.ProductId == u.ProductId)
             select product).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the exception message? Can you post the entire message?

Comment: What kind of linq? -to-sql? EF? nhibernate?

Comment: Related: [LINQ, Unable to create a constant value of type XXX. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13405568/456814).

Comment: Related: [Unable to create a constant value of type Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18929483/456814).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

First way :

Remove `ToList()` in the first query.

Or

```
//instead of retrieving mathings List, retrieve only the productIds you need (which are a List of Primitive types)
var productIdList = db.matchings
.Where(m => m.StoreId == StoreId)
.Select(x => x.ProductId)
.ToList();

var products = db.Products
.Where(p => productIdList
           .Contains(p.ProductId))
.ToList();
```

Or

```
//other way
var produts = db.Products
             .Where(p => db.matchings
                        .Any(m => m.StoreId == StoreId && 
                             m.ProductId == p.ProductId)
                    )
             .ToList();
```

Because I think you're in linq2entities, and you're using a List of Matchings in a query which is not possible (the title of your topic tend to make me believe that's your problem).

Comment: thanks Raphael - all works great but could you explain why I have null reference problem -> should i always do double chek x == y && y == x ?

Comment: hmmm, I updated, was the first version ok for you ? In fact, the problem you faced was not a NRE problem.

Comment: so I put it back. but the first explain maybe better your problem : you tried to used a List<matchings> (enumerated) in a linq2entities query, which is not permitted. Maybe you could even retry your base code just without the ToList() on your "var matchings" query.

Comment: yes, if first query without ToList() method my querys work good too.Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 7):

This looks like a place to use join

```
 var query =
    from product in db.Products
    join matching in db.Matchings
    on product.ProductId equals matching.ProductId into matchGroup
    where matchGroup.Count() > 0 and matching.StoreId == StoreId
    select product;
```

Comment: @agent-j : did I miss something, or isn't `m.StoreId == StoreId` missing ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus, that escaped my notice.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: +1: I first thought of a `join` as well - unless you require the intermediate `matchings` for some reason, a `join` is preferred ...one call to the repository instead of two.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue when writing the following query using collection and EF tables:

```
var result = (from listItem in list
              join dbRecord in Context.MY_TABLE
                  on listItem.MyClass.ID equals dbRecord.ID
              select new { dbRecord, listItem.SomeEnum }).ToList();
```

I could solve it by **changing the source order** in `in`:

```
var result = (from dbRecord in Context.MY_TABLE
              join listItem in list
                  on dbRecord.ID equals listItem.MyClass.ID
              select new { dbRecord, listItem.SomeEnum }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following. It has worked for me as my ProductId os of type nullable.

```
IQueryable<matchings> data = db.matchings.Any(u => product.ProductId.Value == u.ProductId);
```

or this

```
IQueryable<matchings> data = db.matchings.Any(u => product.ProductId.Value.Equals(u.ProductId));
```

This worked in my case as the target id is a nullable type as it points to a 1:0 -> * relationship.