# Unable to create a constant value of type Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, join

I am getting this error for the query below

> Unable to create a constant value of type `API.Models.PersonProtocol`. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

`ppCombined` below is an `IEnumerable` object of `PersonProtocolType`, which is constructed by concat of 2 `PersonProtocol` lists.

Why is this failing? Can't we use LINQ `JOIN` clause inside of `SELECT` of a `JOIN`?

```
var persons = db.Favorites
    .Where(x => x.userId == userId)
    .Join(db.Person, x => x.personId, y => y.personId, (x, y) =>
        new PersonDTO
        {
            personId = y.personId,
            addressId = y.addressId,                   
            favoriteId = x.favoriteId,
            personProtocol = (ICollection<PersonProtocol>) ppCombined
                .Where(a => a.personId == x.personId)
                .Select( b => new PersonProtocol()
                 {
                     personProtocolId = b.personProtocolId,
                     activateDt = b.activateDt,
                     personId = b.personId
                 })
        });
```

Comment: Related: [LINQ, Unable to create a constant value of type XXX. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13405568/456814).

Comment: Related: [Unable to create a constant value - only primitive types](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10862491/456814).

Answer (score 276, accepted):

This cannot work because `ppCombined` is a collection of objects in memory and you cannot join a set of data in the database with another set of data that is in memory. You can try instead to extract the filtered items `personProtocol` of the `ppCombined` collection in memory *after* you have retrieved the other properties from the database:

```
var persons = db.Favorites
    .Where(f => f.userId == userId)
    .Join(db.Person, f => f.personId, p => p.personId, (f, p) =>
        new // anonymous object
        {
            personId = p.personId,
            addressId = p.addressId,   
            favoriteId = f.favoriteId,
        })
    .AsEnumerable() // database query ends here, the rest is a query in memory
    .Select(x =>
        new PersonDTO
        {
            personId = x.personId,
            addressId = x.addressId,   
            favoriteId = x.favoriteId,
            personProtocol = ppCombined
                .Where(p => p.personId == x.personId)
                .Select(p => new PersonProtocol
                {
                    personProtocolId = p.personProtocolId,
                    activateDt = p.activateDt,
                    personId = p.personId
                })
                .ToList()
        });
```

Comment: The key part for me was adding .AsEnumerable() // database query ends here, the rest is a query in memory

Comment: @Slauma So if I'm concerned about performance I should avoid doing this as it would load all data in memory first and then query it. Should I write raw sql for this scenarios?

Comment: It seems like @Arvand has a great point. If you have a large number of records before the filter, this could take a huge bite out of the available memory resources.

Comment: @Slauma "This cannot work because ppCombined is a collection of objects in memory and you cannot join a set of data in the database with another set of data that is in memory." Where can I find documentation about things like this? I’m really lacking knowledge of EF’s limits, and when I try to restrict a query’s result set like this, this incompetence makes itself very apparent and slows me down.

Comment: Good information.  I am adding this exception to my list of least intuitive exception messages ever.  It only makes sense AFTER you understand why it is happening.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was able to resolve the issue by doing the following:

I changed my code from this:

```
var r2 = db.Instances.Where(x => x.Player1 == inputViewModel.InstanceList.FirstOrDefault().Player2 && x.Player2 == inputViewModel.InstanceList.FirstOrDefault().Player1).ToList();
```

To this:

```
var p1 = inputViewModel.InstanceList.FirstOrDefault().Player1;
var p2 = inputViewModel.InstanceList.FirstOrDefault().Player2;
var r1 = db.Instances.Where(x => x.Player1 == p1 && x.Player2 == p2).ToList();
```

Comment: This does not work for me. As `p1` and `p2` are both in the memory whether they are declared anonymously or by a variable name.

Comment: The variable type isn't the issue. In my case the error was caused because was doing a .FirstOrDefault() inside of the Where clause.

Comment: This was the solution for me! Thanku so much @Colin :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if anyone searches for this.
I had the same problem. A select on the query and then doing the where (or join) and using the select variable solved the problem for me.
 (problem was in the collection "Reintegraties" for me)

```
query.Select(zv => new
            {
                zv,
                rId = zv.this.Reintegraties.FirstOrDefault().Id
            })
            .Where(x => !db.Taken.Any(t => t.HoortBijEntiteitId == x.rId
                                             && t.HoortBijEntiteitType == EntiteitType.Reintegratie
                                             && t.Type == TaakType))
            .Select(x => x.zv);
```

hope this helps anyone.

Comment: `zv.this.Reintegraties.FirstOrDefault().Id` potential NullReferenceException

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and what I did and ***solved*** the problem was that I used `AsEnumerable()` just before my Join clause.
here is my query:

```
List<AccountViewModel> selectedAccounts;

 using (ctx = SmallContext.GetInstance()) {
                var data = ctx.Transactions.
                    Include(x => x.Source).
                    Include(x => x.Relation).
                    AsEnumerable().
                    Join(selectedAccounts, x => x.Source.Id, y => y.Id, (x, y) => x).
                    GroupBy(x => new { Id = x.Relation.Id, Name = x.Relation.Name }).
                    ToList();
            }
```

I was wondering why this issue happens, and now I think It is because after you make a query via **LINQ**, the result will be in memory and not loaded into objects, *I don't know* what that state is **but** they are in in some **transitional state** I think. Then when you use `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()`, etc, you are placing them into physical memory objects and the issue is resolving.

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 1):

It's worth adding, since the OP's code sample doesn't provide enough context to prove otherwise, but I received this error as well on the following code:

```cs
public RetailSale GetByRefersToRetailSaleId(Int32 refersToRetailSaleId)
{
    return GetQueryable()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.RefersToRetailSaleId.Equals(refersToRetailSaleId));
}
```

Apparently, I cannot use `Int32.Equals` in this context to compare an Int32 with a primitive int; I had to (safely) change to this:

```cs
public RetailSale GetByRefersToRetailSaleId(Int32 refersToRetailSaleId)
{
    return GetQueryable()
      .FirstOrDefault(x => x.RefersToRetailSaleId == refersToRetailSaleId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add AsEnumerable() andToList() , so it looks like this

```
db.Favorites
    .Where(x => x.userId == userId)
    .Join(db.Person, x => x.personId, y => y.personId, (x, y).ToList().AsEnumerable()

ToList().AsEnumerable()
```