# LINQ Query for Average of column with a join, grouping by the key of the joined table

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, linq, lambda

I have a question regarding LINQ queries using lambda expressions. I have a fairly simple SQL query which takes the average of the rating in table CustomerFeedback, and joins the Movie table on the key movie_id.

I have written the query in SQL and LINQ sql syntax, but writing it in lambda syntax (method syntax) has been a struggle for me.

This is a primitive version of the database scheme:

```
TABLE Movie (
    movie_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title varchar(255) NOT NULL 
    )

    TABLE CustomerFeedback (
    movie_id int, 
    rating int
    CONSTRAINT fk_CustomerFeedbackMovie FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES Movie (movie_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )
```

The query in SQL:
SELECT avg(rating) as AvgRating , m.movie_id as MovieID
FROM CustomerFeedback cf
INNER JOIN Movie m ON m.movie_id = cf.movie_id
GROUP BY m.movie_id

The query in LINQ without LAMBDA syntax which works:

```
var averages =(from movie in _context.Movie
                            join feedback in _context.CustomerFeedback on movie.movie_id equals feedback.movie_id
                            group new {movie, feedback } by new
                            {
                                movie.movie_id
                            }
                            into grouping
                            orderby
                                (double?)grouping.Average(p => p.feedback.rating) ascending 
                            select new
                            {
                                grouping.Key.movie_id,
                                rating_average = (double?)grouping.Average(p => p.feedback.rating)
                            }).Take(10);
```

If anyone could give me a few pointers or a solution it would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The navigation properties as requested by user YacoubMassad

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerFeedback>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.movie_id);

                entity.Property(e => e.movie_id).ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.Property(e => e.comments)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .HasColumnType("varchar");

                entity.Property(e => e.customer_mail_address)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .HasColumnType("varchar");

                entity.Property(e => e.feedback_date).HasColumnType("date");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.customer_mail_addressNavigation).WithMany(p => p.CustomerFeedback).HasForeignKey(d => d.customer_mail_address).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.movie).WithOne(p => p.CustomerFeedback).HasForeignKey<CustomerFeedback>(d => d.movie_id).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
            });
```

Comment: How do your entity classes look like? Do you have navigation properties between the two entities?

Comment: I've edited the post with the navigation properties you requested.

Comment: Why join the two tables if you don't need the name of the movie from first table? Movie Id and avg review can be calculated alone from the 2nd table.

Comment: I think the error starts with a wrong mapping between `Movie` and `CustomerFeedback`. It should be 1:n.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Movie> movies = new List<Movie>() { 
            new Movie(){Id = 1, Name = "The Matrix"},
            new Movie(){Id = 2, Name = "Captain America"}
        };

        List<MovieReview> reviews = new List<MovieReview>() 
        { 
            new MovieReview(){MovieId = 1, Review = 8},
            new MovieReview(){MovieId = 1, Review = 7},
            new MovieReview(){MovieId = 2, Review = 5}
        };

        //var movieReviews = reviews.GroupBy(r => r.MovieId).Select(g => new { MovieId = g.Key, AvgReview = g.Average( r => r.Review) });


        var finalReviews = movies.Join(
            reviews.GroupBy(r => r.MovieId).Select(g => new { MovieId = g.Key, AvgReview = g.Average(r => r.Review) }),
            m => m.Id,
            r => r.MovieId,
            (m, r) => new { Name = m.Name, AvgReview = r.AvgReview }).ToList();

        foreach (var f in finalReviews)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(f.Name + " " + f.AvgReview);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

The entity classes

```
class Movie
{
    public int Id = 0;
    public string Name = "";
}

class MovieReview
{
    public int MovieId = 0;
    public int Review = 0;
}
```

Comment: The foreach loop does not accept anonymous types so I can't print the results to check if it works..

Comment: What is the error (compile or runtime) you are getting? The above code works and prints on console perfectly on my machine.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Runtime I believe, I'm not sure how I can check

Comment: How about if you do `finalReviews.AsEnumerable()`, I edited the answer. I looked into - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929483/unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-only-primitive-types-or-enumeration-ty

Comment: I added `ToList()` to the query. Hopefully, it will run the query against EF. Sorry, I am not that good with EF details. Could you try now?