# Comparing list with list inside another list with linq

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have Job, Tag and TagDto classes. Job class has `ICollection<Tag> Tags` list. I have query that has all the jobs in it as a `IQueryable<Job>` list. I have to now select those Jobs that has one or more tags in the Job.Tags list in `input.Tags` list(which is `List<TagDto>`) as a new list.

```
IQueryabke<Job> query;
List<TagDto> input.Tags;

class Job
{
  ICollection<Tag> Tags;
}
class Tag
{
  string Text;
  other properties...
}
class TagDto
{
  string Text;
  other properties...
}
```

I have tried something like

```
query = query.Where(p => input.Tags.Any(inputTag => p.Tags.Any(tag => tag.Id == inputTag.Id)));
```

But I get the error `"Unable to create a constant value of type 'ProjectA.Tags.TagDto'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."`

Comment: Check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929483/unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-only-primitive-types-or-enumeration-ty

Comment: Thanks but could you help by elaborating how I can implement that to my current query? I'm pretty new with linq and I can't figure out that long query in your link.