# Join Error | Unable to create a constant value of type only primitive

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Very new with LINQ here.

I have the following data in my table (TableA):

```
ID  Name      SubmissionNo
1   Jim       A-1
2   Andy      A-2
3   Rick      A-2
4   Mary      A-3
5   Zim       A-4
6   Loren     A-1
```

I then need to create a query which will allow me to get from that table, those records which have duplicate submission numbers.

Here's my solution so far (Context is the database context):

```
var duplicates = (from tbl in Context.TableA.AsNoTracking()
                  group tbl by tbl.SubmissionNo into grp
                  select new { count = grp.Count(), submissionNo = grp.Key})
                 .Where(x => x.count > 1)
                 .OrderBy(y => y.submissionNo).ToList();
```

The variable duplicates then contains the record:

```
count  submissionNo
2      A-1
2      A-2
```

I then write the main query which will allow me to get all the records from TableA which has duplicate submissionNo

```
var myList = (from tbl in Context.TableA.AsNoTracking()
              join dup in duplicates on tbl.SubmissionNo equals dup.submissionNo
              select new 
              { 
                ID = tbl.ID, 
                Name = tbl.Name, 
                SubmissionNo = tbl.SubmissionNo 
              })
              .ToList();
```

I am then getting an error for the myList query with

Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous Type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

I think there must be a better way to do this as from the TableA above, I practically want the following results:

```
ID  Name      SubmissionNo
1   Jim       A-1
2   Andy      A-2
3   Rick      A-2
6   Loren     A-1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929483/unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-only-primitive-types-or-enumeration-ty

Comment: Hi @Zysce - I did checked the link provided but it does not do the same thing I wanted.

Comment: use duplicates as a list of submission numbers only and then in your last Linq query instead of join try using where list contains

Comment: Do you also get this error if you don't do the ToList in your Duplicates, so if you let Duplicates be of type IQueryable, instead of a List?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query, slightly modified, has all information you need:

```
var myList  = from tbl in Context.TableA.AsNoTracking()
              group tbl by tbl.SubmissionNo into grp
              where grp.Count() > 1
              from item in grp
              select new
              { 
                  count = grp.Count(),
                  submissionNo = grp.Key,
                  item.Name,
              );
```

The pattern `group into grp - from item in grp` is a commonly used query pattern to group items and then *flatten* the group again, while keeping in touch with the group data (like `Count()` and `Key`).

Now you don't need the join anymore and the exception doesn't occur. By the way, the exception tells you that EF can only handle joins with collections of primitive types (`int` etc.), because it has to translate the whole expression into SQL. There's simply no translation for rich objects like `TableA`.

By the way, the query can be improved by removing the repeated `Count()`:

```
var myList  = from tbl in Context.TableA.AsNoTracking()
              group tbl by tbl.SubmissionNo into grp
              let count = grp.Count()
              where count > 1
              from item in grp
              select new
              { 
                  count = count,
                  submissionNo = grp.Key,
                  item.Name,
              );
```

This will generate a more efficient SQL statement containing one `COUNT` instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

Since Entity Framework does not support joining in-memory collections of objects with database collections, a common workaround for this is to filter using `Contains`.

First, you need to get the IDs to filter on:

```
var duplicates = (from tbl in Context.TableA.AsNoTracking()
                  group tbl by tbl.SubmissionNo into grp
                  select new { count = grp.Count(), submissionNo = grp.Key})
                 .Where(x => x.count > 1)
                 .OrderBy(y => y.submissionNo)
                 .ToList();
var duplicateIds = duplicates.Select(x => x.submissionNo).ToList();
```

And then change your query to perform a `WHERE...IN` instead of a `JOIN`:

```
var myList = (from tbl in Context.TableA.AsNoTracking()
              where duplicateIDs.Contains(tbl.SubmissionNo)
              select new 
              { 
                ID = tbl.ID, 
                Name = tbl.Name, 
                SubmissionNo = tbl.SubmissionNo 
              })
              .ToList();
```