# Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to understand why I am having to do something, and if there is a better way to do it.

This is my query that gets a list of orders and items:

```
 var orderItemDetail = (from o in db.Order_Detail
                               where o.Id == orderIdToGet
                               join i in db.item_detail on o.Id equals i.order_id into FakeLeftJoin
                               from items in FakeLeftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               select new
                               {
                                   o,
                                   i = FakeLeftJoin
                               }).ToArray();
```

I then need to step through it, and check if a item already exists.
This code works where I get the OrderIdToCheck then search for it:

```
 foreach (var orderItem in orderItemDetail)
            {
                int OrderIdToCheck = orderItem.i.First().Id;

                //check if it already exists
                var itemCheck = (from i in db.Stop_Items
                                 where (i.stop_detail_id == currentStop.Id && i.item_detail_id == OrderIdToCheck)
                                 select i).FirstOrDefault().item_detail;
```

But if I embed the part to get the Id as per below:

```
 foreach (var orderItem in orderItemDetail)
            {
                //int OrderIdToCheck = orderItem.i.First().Id;

                //check if it already exists
                var itemCheck = (from i in db.Stop_Items
                                 where (i.stop_detail_id == currentStop.Id && i.item_detail_id == orderItem.i.First().Id)
                                 select i).FirstOrDefault().item_detail;
```

Then I get the following error:

Message=Unable to create a constant value of type 'process_orders_to_stops.item_detail'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
  Source=EntityFramework

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to create a constant value of type Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929483/unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-only-primitive-types-or-enumeration-ty)

Comment: Yes, it does indeed.  If you want to put it as a answer I'll close this out.