# Why only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context using EF?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, join, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

In my application I try to execute a **Join** query using **EntityFramework**, *Repository Pattern*, It is throwing bellow error. What is the **problem** in the ***link query***? Let me explain in details

**Error Description**

> Unable to create a constant value of type '**Anonymous type**'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

**Initialization**

```
_repository = new GenericRepository<WeeklyEntry>();
_repositoryGroup = new GenericRepository<Group>();
_repositoryGroupMember = new GenericRepository<GroupMember>();
```

**Fetching Logic**

```
 var groups = _repositoryGroup.GetAll().OrderBy(o => o.ID)
                              .Select(s => new { s.ID, s.Name }).ToList();
 var groupMembers = _repositoryGroupMember.GetAll().OrderBy(o => o.ID)
                                          .Select(s => new { s.GroupID, s.ID, s.Name })
                                          .ToList();
```

**Main Query [Not Working]**

```
 var results = (from we in _repository.GetAll()
                join g in groups on we.GroupID equals g.ID into grpjoin
                from g in grpjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join gm in groupMembers on we.DepositedByMemberID equals gm.ID into gmjoin
                from gm in gmjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where gm.GroupID == g.ID
                select new
                {
                     GroupID = g.ID,
                     GroupName = g.Name,
                     MemberID = grpmresult.ID,
                     grpmresult.Name,
                     we.ID                                  
                 }).ToList();
```

To try to achieve bellow **SQL Query**

```
select w.GroupID, g.Name, gm.Name, w.ID
from [dbo].[WeeklyEntry] as w
left outer join [dbo].[Group] as g on g.ID = w.GroupID
left outer join [dbo].[GroupMember] as gm on gm.GroupID = g.ID
AND gm.ID = w.DepositedByMemberID
order by w.GroupID
```

**Strange Findings**

If I include `.ToList();` with each query like `from we in _repository.GetAll().ToList()` the entire query will work & give expected result **without Any ERROR**!!!

So if I convert each query return type to In-memory Or `IEnumerable<>`  it is working as expected without any error but `IQueryable<>` query not working as expected.

**New Code Snippet [Working]**

```
var results = (from we in _repository.GetAll().ToList()
                join g in groups on we.GroupID equals g.ID into grpjoin
                from g in grpjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join gm in groupMembers on we.DepositedByMemberID equals gm.ID into gmjoin
                from gm in gmjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where gm.GroupID == g.ID
                select new {...}.ToList();
```

Comment: Could you post signature of `_repository.GetAll()`?

Comment: @sam : already in the post `_repository = new GenericRepository<WeeklyEntry>();` IQueryable<>

Answer (score 1):

You can't join a database table with an in-memory collection (in your case, `List`):

[Unable to create a constant value of type Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929483/unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-only-primitive-types-or-enumeration-ty)

You're converting these to in-memory collections by calling `ToList`:

```
 var groups = _repositoryGroup.GetAll().OrderBy(o => o.ID)
                              .Select(s => new { s.ID, s.Name }).ToList();
 var groupMembers = _repositoryGroupMember.GetAll().OrderBy(o => o.ID)
                                          .Select(s => new { s.GroupID, s.ID, s.Name })
                                          .ToList();
```

which you then try and join in the next bit of code.

If you simply remove those `ToList` calls, the join should work (you can keep the one for the final result, if you prefer it).

Remember that `IEnumerable` is lazy and will only actually run a SQL query if you "execute it" by iterating (usually via a `foreach` loop or some function like `ToList`).

Comment: If I remove `ToList()` it will through another **ERROR** `The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts`

Comment: It sounds like you are using multiple context objects (inside your repository classes). If you look in the constructor of your GenericRepository<T>, you are likely creating a new context each time. Instead, pass the context via the constructor, and use the same one across your repositories.

Comment: @ShubhajyotiGhosh Use a DI framework (ASP.NET Core has one built-in) and add your data context as `Scoped`.

Comment: @MohammadDehghan: Project dosn't content any `DI` so unable to use it here. Do you feel is it due to`Scoped`  !!! If we use 'DI` we never have o face this issue ??

Comment: @ShubhajyotiGhosh as **oofmycode** said, your second error comes from the fact that you are creating a new DataContext in each repository, and because of that, you cannot join queries coming from different repositories (the error you get it clear). Since you are returning plain `IQueryable`s from your repositories, you gain nothing from using them. Get rid of them, and use the DataContext directly.

Comment: @MohammadDehghan: `IQueryable` will work for single query in current project and a mix and match scenario, join will work if you try to join two table one is using `IEnumrable` return type and another one using `IQueryale` it will work as expected.

Comment: @ShubhajyotiGhosh Sorry, but I don't understand what you said. I'm saying, *do not use Repository pattern with EF* (See [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220126/47839) and [here](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/)). Instead of using those repositories, use the `DbContext` directly, and your error vanishes.

Comment: @MohammadDehghan I understand your concern, I know EF using UOW and relevant, but my problem is different & here I am looking for proper cause of the problem.

Comment: @ShubhajyotiGhosh The cause: joining data from different DbContexts. That's all. Please read "oofmycode" answer and comment.

Comment: @MohammadDehghan plz read all the comment. "oofmycode" explanation is something different.He question about `ToLost()` relevance !!! And I already told him, Why I am using it. And for your information. I already join two table and working as expected. But more than two table (> 2) malfunctioning..

Comment: @ShubhajyotiGhosh The new error you are running is not caused by removing the `ToList()` calls to solve the first error; rather, the first error was being thrown before this error, so you never saw it before. Removing `ToList` will keep your query "lazy" (as I mentioned in the answer), and is the correct way to solve the first error. Changing your `GenericRepository<T>` constructor code to take a reference to a shared context object for all of your repositories (rather than create a new one every time) is how you solve the second error. They are completely unrelated errors.

Comment: @oofmycode If I remove `ToList()` it will through another **ERROR** The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain!

You have a `GenericRepository<T>` class, that is something like this:

```
public class GenericRepository<T>
{
    MyDbContext dbContext;
    public GenericRepository()
    {
        dbContext = new MyDbContext();
    }
    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

and then you have:

```
_repository = new GenericRepository<WeeklyEntry>();
_repositoryGroup = new GenericRepository<Group>();
_repositoryGroupMember = new GenericRepository<GroupMember>();

var groups = _repositoryGroup.GetAll().ToList(); // other query operators are irrelevant and removed
var groupMembers = _repositoryGroupMember.GetAll().ToList();
```

Calling `ToList()` runs your queries and bring the data to memory. Now you have two **in-memory** collection (`List<T>`).

When you write:

```
var results = from we in _repository.GetAll() // <-- this is IQueryable<T>
              join g in groups                // <-- this is List<T> (IEnumerable<T>)
              on we.GroupID equals g.ID into grpjoin
              ...
```

you are joining an IQueryable, with an in-memory list. When running this query, EF has no way to know that your in-memory lists (`groups` and `groupMembers`) are actually queries from the database. It only sees two lists, containing some data. It has no way to translate that into SQL and hence throws an error.

To fix this, you should remove calls to `ToList()`. That way, you have three `IQueryable`s that are joined together. EF can translate that into SQL, only if they are from *a single `DbContext`*. And since they are not, it throws another error, telling you exactly that.

You create an instance `DbContext` for each of the `GenericRepository<T>` instances. So, `groups`, `groupMembers` and `we` come from three different DbContexts.

To solve this error, you should somehow manage to use a single `DbContext` for all your `GenericRepository<T>`s.

For example:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    var groups = dbContext.Set<Group>();
    var groupMembers = dbContext.Set<GroupMember>();

    var results = from we in dbContext.Set<WeeklyEntry>()
                  join g in groups
                  on we.GroupID equals g.ID into grpjoin
                  ...

}
```

Comment: I got your piint, here I  am unable to use any DI, so i can do one thing, change little bit into repository to get resolve the error. Without 'ToList() ' implementation. By the way now query able to produce correct results using 'ToList() ' there was relationship issue in the DB, that's why I am getting error.

Comment: Calling `ToList()` brings your whole data into memory, and runs all the joins in-memory. This ruins the whole point of using a relational database!